# sharingd wants to use the ".kc328-0" keychain

Tags: macos, password, keychain, airdrop

I was helping a coworker solve an issue with Xcode and followed these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023639/xcode-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-errsecinternalcomponen

And clicked "lock all keychains"

Now, whenever anyone opens anything air drop around me, I'm getting this popup 3-6 times in a row:

[image: sharingd wants to use the ".kc328-0" keychain]

Googling this returns 0 results.

How do I make it stop? Where do I find this password? What is .kc328-0? Help.